# style not working on ul li on countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Style not working on `ul li`... It is only showing without any style.
I'm creating countdown of time by JavaScript but its not working....
JavaScript function is working but my `ul li` could not get style on output.

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul#countdown li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 54px;
        margin-bottom: 4em;
        text-align: center;
        /*padding-top: 20px;*/
        background: black;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }

    ul#countdown li span {
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul#countdown li span::before {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 31px;
    }

    ul#countdown li p.timeRefDays,
    ul#countdown li p.timeRefHours,
    ul#countdown li p.timeRefMinutes,
    ul#countdown li p.timeRefSeconds {
        /*margin-top: 1em;*/
        color: #a89256;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: .875em;
    }
    .timer-area .logo img {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px;
    }

</style>
<script>

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

//            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
//            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
//            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
//            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';

            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<ul id='countdown'>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li><span class='days'>days</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefDays'>"+ days +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li><span class='hours'>hours</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefHours'>"+ hours +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li> <span class='minutes'>minutes</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefMinutes'>"+ minutes +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li> <span class='seconds'>seconds</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefSeconds'>"+ seconds +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</ul>";
        }
        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }
</script>

<div class="row">
    <!-- <h3>New Products</h3> --> 
    <?php //if ($this->getProducts()->getSize() > '0') { ?>

        <?php foreach ($this->getProducts() as $_Product) { ?> 

            <?php //echo $timespan = strtotime($_Product['special_to_date']) - strtotime($_Product['special_from_date']);exit; ?>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
                <div><a href="<?php echo $_Product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_Product, 'small_image')->resize(145, 200) ?>" alt="<?php echo $_Product->getName(); ?>"></a></div>
                <div align="center"><h4><?php echo $_Product->getName(); ?></h4></div>
                <div align="center"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_Product->getPrice()); ?></div>
                <?php //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_Product->toArray());exit; ?>


                <script>
                    CountDownTimer("<?php echo $_Product['special_to_date'] ?>", "newcountdown<?php echo $_Product['sku']; ?>");
                </script>
                <div id="newcountdown<?php echo $_Product['sku']; ?>">

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php //} ?>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please create a working fiddle, without the PHP functions, just plain html.

Comment: Aside from that, you should save the HTML you want to add into a variable and only do the DOM call once. Also, this can't work as your javascript is calling to make changes to an id that at the time does not exist yet (you call JS _before_ the div is written). There is so much wrong with this code. `align=center` on divs? Everything based on the id..?

Comment: @Sebsemillia  yes sure http://jsfiddle.net/deepakworld86/zkc4nuz9/3/

Comment: how do you want it? since its not working do yo have a visual? like a.jpg file

Comment: @argentum47  like this http://codepen.io/christophrumpel/pen/jcHJK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you wrote  `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<ul id='countdown'>";`  the   tag was getting closed instantly with the `<li>` elements outside, changed it to 1 string instead of all the += and the formatting from CSS applied and the `<ul>` closed at the right place.

from

```
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<ul id='countdown'>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li><span class='days'>days</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefDays'>"+ days +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li><span class='hours'>hours</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefHours'>"+ hours +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li> <span class='minutes'>minutes</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefMinutes'>"+ minutes +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<li> <span class='seconds'>seconds</span>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p class='timeRefSeconds'>"+ seconds +"</p>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</li>";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

to

```
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<ul id='countdown'>" +
        "<li><span class='days'>days</span>" +
        "<p class='timeRefDays'>" + days + "</p>" +
        "<li>" +
        "<li><span class='hours'>hours</span>" +
        "<p class='timeRefHours'>" + hours + "</p>" +
        "</li>" +
        "<li> <span class='minutes'>minutes</span>" +
        "<p class='timeRefMinutes'>" + minutes + "</p>" +
        "</li>" +
        "<li> <span class='seconds'>seconds</span>" +
        "<p class='timeRefSeconds'>" + seconds + "</p>" +
        "</li>" +
        "</ul>"
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fqs3L4pr/